# Vue router hooks in NUXT middleware

Tags: vuejs2, middleware, nuxt.js

I am trying to close down the sidebar when my user changes route

```
export default function({ store }) {
    store.commit("TOGGLE_SIDEBAR");
}
```

The issue is this calls it as soon as the site loads

I try this

```
export default function({ app, store }) {
  app.router.beforeEach((to, next) => {
    store.commit("TOGGLE_SIDEBAR");
    next();
  });
}
```

I get `next is not a function.`

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) `router.beforeEach(...)` expects a function with 3 arguments : `to`, `from` and `next`.

As you've passed only two arguments, the `next` argument you are trying to call is in fact the `from` Route.

Add a third parameter like below :

```
export default function({ app, store }) {
  app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.commit("TOGGLE_SIDEBAR");
    next();
  });
}
```